# CSS positive padding with negative margin

Tags: css

I saw the following css in the Sonata project.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="header"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 -20px; /* negative indent the amount of the padding to maintain the grid system */
}

.header {
    padding: 20px 20px 10px;
    margin: -20px -20px 20px;
}
```

My question is, what is the purpose/advantage of having positive paddings and then negate them with negative margins? The code does have a comment on negative margin but I don't really get it. Why not just set both margin and padding to 0?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the data in the content element, is it just the header? Could it be that some other data in the content needs to be padded but the header needs to stay at the top?

Comment: it's probably a hack to support older browsers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please have a look at the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) -- you'll notice that border is between padding and margin, and thus the above is most likely used to push the borders outwards.

Answer (score 8):

One common use of padding offset by a negative margin like this is to fix browsers navigating to the wrong place when using fragment identifiers in combination with a `position: fixed` header.

Suppose I have a page like this...

```
<div class="fixed-navbar">Navbar Stuff!</div>

<a href="#interesting-content">Link to interesting content below</a>
<p>Lots of content that takes up space and makes the page scroll...</p>

<h2 id="interesting-content">Some interesting content</h2>
<p>Bla bla bla</p>

<p>More really tall content</p>
```

... where the `.fixed-navbar` has this CSS:

```
position: fixed;
height: 50px;
```

When I visit my page and click the link, the browser will scroll the `<h2>` up to the top of the page... resulting in it underlapping the fixed navbar! This is probably undesirable. ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2whc291/1/))

However, we can fix this with the following CSS:

```
#interesting-content {
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2whc291/2/))

Now, when we ask the browser to navigate to the fragment identifier, it navigates to the top of the padding, one navbar-height above the actual content. This positions the actual content right where we want it.

Comment: Clever! As fixed navbars are now widespread, this css trick should also be widely used.  Solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Box-sizing could help you clear your code is using css3: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/